# SASS nested structure messes up @media queries precedence

Tags: css, responsive-design, sass, media-queries

See following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m94jB/1/):

**HTML:**

```
<div class='header'>Header</div>
<div class='main'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='cell lg-4'>
            content
        </div>
        <div class='cell lg-4'>
            content
        </div>
        <div class='cell lg-4'>
            content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**SASS**:

```
.header {
    display: none;
}

.main {
    .row {
        width: 100%;

        .cell {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: red;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
    }
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
    .header {
        display: block;
    }

    .cell {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-left: 1px;
        float: left;
        &.lg-4 {
            width: 33%
        }
    }
}
```

By looking at this code you would think it does the following:

- Show by default a mobile design: i.e. cells are stacked vertically and take all screen space and the header is hidden
- Above 600px: Become a row of 3 cells taking up 1/3 of the horizontal space each and show the header.

If you try it in the fiddle, you will see that in both viewports (above and below 600px) the cells are shown stacked vertically **however** the header does get hidden or shown as specified in the media query.

After searching for quite some time, I realised the query becomes effective for cells only if the media query adopts the *exact* same nested structure as the normal sass code, i.e.:

```
@media (min-width: 600px) {
    .header {
        display: block;
    }

    .main {
        .row {        
            .cell {
                margin-bottom: 0;
                margin-left: 1px;
                float: left;
                &.lg-4 {
                    width: 33%
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why does this happen, and more importantly, how to avoid having to reuse the same structure in media queries? (the workaround for this fiddle is simple, but my actual code has more than 10 to 20 nested variables so adding a media query for the 20th element would force me to add 19 useless lines of nested variables, quickly overloading the code and making it difficult to read)

Maybe I am doing this wrong, as I am rather new to making my own responsive design, so am I missing some best practices that avoid this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `.main .row .cell` is more specific than `.cell` in a `@media` query.

It's good practice to reduce nesting as much as possible in order to prevent this exact situation happening as it's a pain to get around. Some other problems that come out of a lot of nesting is that it makes styles non-modular and difficult to reuse, as they rely on the exact structure, it can also bad for performance.

I recommend splitting up the top section like this:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9PqsE/)

```
.header {
    display: none;
}

.main {
    /* ... */
}

.row {
    width: 100%;
}

.cell {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
    .header {
        display: block;
    }

    .cell {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-left: 1px;
        float: left;
        &.lg-4 {
            width: 33%
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I discovered SASS since learning Rails, and I thought nesting everything was the 'good practice'. In which case would you use nesting then, if it impacts performance and causes problems?

Comment: The performance isn't the main issue, it's that you're designing your styles to not be reusable. The best way to organize your code is not by nesting but by splitting it into different .scss files and then merging them all into one when you compile.

Comment: Nesting is good and necessary sometimes though, a good rule that I use is when I find myself at 3 levels deep I make sure I really need to be there.

Comment: @DanielImms Nesting is never considered "good practice".  It is there as a convenience to make writing out selectors less tedious.  Always use the shortest possible selector to get the job done.

Comment: @cimmanon nesting unnecessarily is bad practice, need it sometimes though, that's why it's there. eg. `.something { &::after {} }`, `.active { .something {} }`, etc.

Comment: @DanielImms I did not say "never nest" or that it is a "bad practice", I just said that it is not considered a "good practice".  Sometimes the shortest possible selector to get the job done *is* long.  Nesting will never improve performance since longer selectors are more costly for the browser to process.

Comment: Thank you both for your insights on the subject!